Error Connecting to Elasticsearch on Render Deployment: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND elasticsearch
I have a Node.js application that works perfectly when running locally with docker-compose up --build. It connects to both MongoDB and Elasticsearch without any issues. However, when I deploy the application on Render, I encounter the following error when making a POST request to an endpoint that interacts with Elasticsearch:
Error indexing document: ConnectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND elasticsearch
    at SniffingTransport._request (/app/node_modules/@elastic/transport/lib/Transport.js:609:31)
    ...

My docker-compose.yml file looks like this:
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      MONGO_URI: ${MONGO_URI}
      ELASTICSEARCH_URI: ${ELASTICSEARCH_URI}
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - elasticsearch
    networks:
      - app-network

  mongo:
    image: mongo:5.0
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - app-network

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.10
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    networks:
      - app-network

In my .env file, I set the following values:
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.mongodb.net/mydb?retryWrites=true&w=majority
ELASTICSEARCH_URI=http://elasticsearch:9200

In my code, I connect to Elasticsearch like this:
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch');
const client = new Client({ node: process.env.ELASTICSEARCH_URI });


Locally, everything works fine when I run docker-compose up --build.
On Render, MongoDB connects successfully, but Elasticsearch fails with getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND elasticsearch.
I suspect this happens because the hostname elasticsearch cannot be resolved on Render.

Questions:

How can I fix this issue, and how can I deploy Elasticsearch on Render using Docker?

Additional Context:
Here are my Render server logs:
Error indexing document: ConnectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND elasticsearch
...

Any guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Are you setting up a private network for your containers?

I believe render enables users to deploy Docker applications automatically with elasticsearch, so I have not set up any private networks for containers.
